# MongoDb linq and in memory querying. How do I know it queries in the DB

Tags: c#, performance, linq, mongodb

This has been asked many times before and I have got different answers from different people.

Some say that when:

```
collection.AsQueryable<object>().Where()
```

is used the "Where" operation is done in memory and others say it is converted to a mongo query.

When I reference: using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

I have access to AsQueryable() but I can't chain a "Where" clause at the end of that without referencing System.Linq.

So i did a test by inserting 80 000 complex objects into my local mongo db and did a simple query. It takes about 5 seconds to return any given page of 50 of these objects. This leads me to believe its done in memory.

The documentation seems to advocate querying using normal Linq:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

But in the examples it doesn't reference System.Linq. It also states that Linq can be used over version 1.8. My version is higher than that so I should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you apply these kind of functions to `collection.AsQueryable<object>()`, it'll be done in MongoDb. If you do it after applying `.ToList()` function or any similar function that actually reads from the enumerate, it'll be done in memory.

To check it by yourself, do `AsQueryable()` and `Where()` in separate instructions and check it with the debugger.